# Multiple Input IDs in jQuery to Change One Span in Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an 'X' icon in the span that I would like to show until BOTH #first-name AND #last-name are not blank.  I have tried many ideas written on Stack that just don't seem to work for this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="first-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last">
    </div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</div>
```

**Current jQuery**
(this is the latest code I've tried from a Stack suggestions and it works the same as the others have)

```
  $("#last-name").bind("focus change keyup", function(){
    var emptyInputs = $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
      return $.trim( this.value ).length > 0;
    });        
    if(emptyInputs) {
      $(this).parent().next("span").removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().next("span").removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok").fadeIn("slow");          
    }
  });
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** And I would also like the 'X' icon to be displayed when the #first-name has focus, keyup, etc. instead of just relying on the #last-name for the display.

Comment: `emptyInputs` will always resolve to `true` in the `if` statement, because it will always hold a jQuery object.

Comment: You're only binding to `#last-name`, so changing `#first-name` won't result in any change

Comment: Because you want to ensure that both are not blank, that means you if at least one is blank, the `if` should fail. Therefore change the `return` statement in the `.filter()` to do `=== 0` instead of `> 0`, and then change the `if` statement to `if (emptyInputs.length)`

Comment: @cookiemonster - Thank you, that makes sense. However the code still didn't work for both.

Answer (score 1):

Multiples problem in your code. First, this line :

```
 $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]');
```

Doing that is exactly like `$(this)`. it should be :

```
var emptyInputs = $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim( this.value ).length > 0;
});
```

Then, `if(emptyInputs)` will always return true since `emptyInputs` is a jQuery object (truthy value). It should be :

```
if(emptyInputs.length)
```

Then the event bind is only on the `last-name`. You need to add first name :

```
$("#last-name, #first-name").on()
```

But with that this line will not work anymore :

```
 $(this).parent().next("span")
```

Change it you that :

```
 $(this).siblings("span")
```

Caching your variable would be a good performance gain in this example.

---

Here an optimized code :

```
var myInput = $("#first-name, #last-name").on("focus change keyup", function () {
    var fill = true
    myInput.each(function(){
        console.log($.trim(this.value).length)
        return fill = !!$.trim(this.value).length;
    })
    $(this).closest('.form-group')
    .find("span.glyphicon")
    .toggleClass("glyphicon-ok", fill)
    .toggleClass("glyphicon-remove", !fill);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s34La/2/

Comment: This worked!  Thank you! Is there a way to show the 'X' icon when the user is focused on the #first-name input?  Right now it only shows the icon when on the #last-name.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $inputs = $("#first-name, #last-name").on("focus change keyup", function () {
        var emptyInputs = $inputs.filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
        });

        var $icon = $(this).closest('.form-group').find("span.glyphicon")
        if (emptyInputs.length) {
            $icon.removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
        } else {
            $icon.removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s34La/)

- check the length of `emptyInputs` because `emptyInputs` is a jQuery object which will always be truthy
- add the listener to both the input fields
- since both the fields are there find the icon element within the same form-group instead of using next()

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  Same question as below - Is there a way to show the 'X' icon when the user is focused on the #first-name input?  Right now it only shows the icon when on the #last-name.

Answer (score 1):

What about something more simple like

```
if($("#first-name").val().length == 0 || $("#last-name").val().length == 0){
    $(this).parent().next("span").removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove").fadeIn("slow");
} else {
    $(this).parent().next("span").removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok").fadeIn("slow");          
}
```

Comment: Ya, I tried something like that and it still didn't work. Thank you.